# Comparing algorithm running times expressed in complex form

Tags: performance, algorithm, math

I know how to compare running times of different algorithms.

Sometimes it is obvious, sometimes it requires simplifications, and sometimes dividing and using L'Hopital's rule to see if it converges to a constant or 0.

However, how do you compare the functions if they are in a complex form?

For example, how would you compare
[image]

and `n`?

Of course, I want a rigorous proof.

Comment: it's on a case by case basis.  i don't think there' a general rule.  for your example, i'd start by simplifying that 2^ expression.  you can start by converting the exponent to a term involving log base 2, and observe that 2^(log base 2 of k) = k.

Comment: @thang there is exponent sqrt(2)-0.4 to the log exponent. How do I apply the fact that 2^(log base 2 of k) = k here?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the first simplification is to remove the `sqrt(2)-0.4` power.  That power is so close to `1` that it hardly makes a difference.  Apologies if your comparisons require this distinction.  There's probably an exponentiation rule for this, but I can't remember my maths all that well.

The next is to use the log rule to factor out **log<sub>96</sub>n**.

The equivalent is **log<sub>2</sub>n / log<sub>2</sub>96**.  Now you have **2** to the power of the former.  **log<sub>2</sub>96** is just a constant (approximately 6.585).  You can factor this out (because it becomes insignificant as `n` increases), or leave it in and use another log rule.   Let's leave it in:

**log<sub>2</sub>n / log<sub>2</sub>96** becomes **log<sub>2</sub>n<sup>(log<sub>2</sub>96)<sup>-1</sup></sup>**

The whole thing simplifies down to **n<sup>(log<sub>2</sub>96)-1</sup>**.  Or if you made the additional simplification, you would have got **2 ^ log<sub>2</sub>n**, which is just **n**.

Since you wanted to *compare* to **n**, then it would seem the first result is more relevant, which is approximately **0.15n**.

Comment: Sorry. My comparison requires the `sqrt(2)-0.4' power.

Answer (score 0):

It is particular to each problem. In this case suppose n = 96^k and 96 = 2^m.

n vs expression can be rewritten as:

```
2^(m*k) vs 2^(k ^(sqrt(2) - 0.4))
```

Since 2, m, k, sqrt(k) - 0.4 are both > 0, the comparison becomes

```
(m * k) vs k ^(sqrt(2) - 0.4)
```

or

```
m vs k ^(sqrt(2) - 1.4)
```

But m = log 96 to base 2 which is fixed (6.585) while k is unbounded

Hence the expression (RHS) will be bigger.